# How do you texture a large objects without the texure being blurry?

Tags: texturing

Whenever I add a texture in my large object (a large and long platform), the texture, when viewed close, is blurry. The only thing I can do is use a very large texture. Is there any other way?

Comment: Hello :). The bluriness is to prevent low-res textures from looking pixelated. Do you want the texture visibly pixelated? It will make it sharp.

Comment: You can use repeating texture.

Comment: @FFeller: I've seen that recommened on some threads but I'm not sure how to go about it. Do you have any link that I indicating how this is done? Because i have a seamless texture but it seems it just stretches to the whole object.

Comment: related, from BlenderGuru: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc